# drop-down list design in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, select, html-select

Opera, Chrome: http://s23.postimg.org/swo0s3bnv/opeera.png 
Firefox: http://oi44.tinypic.com/2zthd2t.jpg

my css:

```
width: 170px;
height: 25px;
font-family: arial;
color:#9E9E9F;
font-size: 12px;
border-color:#EFEFEF;
border-width: 1px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance:none;
background: url(../img/select-ar.fw.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 150px 8px;
cursor: pointer;
padding-left: 3px;
letter-spacing: 0.6pt;
```

What does it want?

how can I fix it in firefox?

Answer (score 0):

You can only make this with a `:after` elment, which overlays the original `select`